# Existence Proof: $T(v_i)=w_i$ for all $i=1,2,3,\dots,n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

### Theorem to prove:

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a linearly independent set in a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and let $w_1,\dots,w_n$ be arbitrary  vectors in a vector space $W$. Then there exists a linear map $T:V \rightarrow W$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$ for all $i=1,2,3,\dots,n$.

---

### How should I change this?

Let ${\mathscr{B}}=\{v_1,\dots,v_n,v_{n+1},\dots,v_m\}$ be a basis for $V$ and ${\mathscr{C}}=\{u_1,\dots,u_p\}$ a basis for $W$, then 
\begin{eqnarray}
w_1  & = & a_{11}u_1+a_{21}u_2+\cdots+a_{p1}u_p = T(v_1)\\
w_2 & = & a_{12}u_1+a_{22}u_2+\cdots+a_{p2}u_p = T(v_2)\\
\vdots & & \hspace{6cm} \vdots \\
w_n & = & a_{1n}u_1+a_{2n}u_2+\cdots+a_{pn}u_p  = T(v_n)\\
w_{n+1} & = & ??? = T(v_{n+1})\\
\vdots & & \hspace{2cm} \vdots \\
w_m & = & ??? = T(v_m),
\end{eqnarray}
so $\cdots$

Comment: You don't know that such a map $T$ exists, so you can't use it.

Comment: In the problem, you already have the terms $v_i$, and they are not given to be a basis. Probably bad idea to create a new $v_i$.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have that $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a basis. However, you can complete the set to a basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_{n+1},\ldots,v_m)$. Then, the universal property of a basis lets you set, say, $T(v_i) = w_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, and $T(v_i) = 0$ for $i=n+1,\ldots,m$, and extend this to a linear map on the whole of $V$.

Comment: Extend what to a linear map on the whole of $V$?

Comment: @Trancot Extend $T$. If you have a set function defined on a basis, you can extend it to the whole of the vector space by linearity. This is the "universal property" of the basis, or more precisely, of the vector space, as a free object on its basis.

Comment: @Trancot To be more precise, here on any vector $v = \sum_i^m a_i v_i$ expressed in terms of the basis, we have $T(v) = \sum_i^m a_i T(v_i) = \sum_i^n a_i w_i$.